# My JTable is not Updating

Tags: java, jtable

What I'm doing:

orderPage panel contains: a button,a JTable(summary)

myChild panel contains: textFields for accepting input from the user.

On a press of a button, a myChild panel opens up (without closing orderPage) and asks the user for some input. What i want to do is, based on the data provided by user, my Jtable(summary) gets updated with the new data, Which is not happening.

My code:

```
public class orderPage extends javax.swing.JPanel {
public static JTable summary = new JTable();
public static DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) summary.getModel();

/** Creates new form orderPage1 */
    public orderPage() {
        initComponents();
        tableContainer.setViewportView(summary);
    }

    public static void addItem(int itemId,String itemName,int price,int qty,int amt)
    {
        model.addRow(new Object[]{itemId,itemName,price,qty,amt});
    }
```

By calling addRow method (of orderPage) from child panel, my JTable is not updating.
Am i doing something wrong? Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you actually reach the addItem method()? At which point exactly is your code failing, when you run the debugger?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there. The row is adding, but the table is not reflecting the changes. In order to see the new row that you added, you need to refresh the JTable. You can do this by calling fireTableDataChanged(). For example:

```
public static void addItem(int itemId,String itemName,int price,int qty,int amt)
{
    model.addRow(new Object[]{itemId,itemName,price,qty,amt});

    // now that the new row has been added, refresh the table to reflect this
    model.fireTableDataChanged();
}
```

Comment: No, you should need to call `fireXxx` methods externally of a `DefaultTableModel` (or any `TableModel`), `addRow` already does this. The `fireXxx` methods are for internal use for the model only

Comment: My mistake. I didn't realise that fireXXX actually gets automatically called through an update to the DefaultTableModel.